# What does the television-esque film style in the episode "I Am Anne Frank, Part II" represent?

Tags: film-techniques, american-horror-story

In the second season episode of *American Horror Story*, "I Am Anne Frank, Part II", we're told that Anne Frank is actually Charlotte Brown, delusional and obsessed wife of Jim Brown, a new character to that specific episode.

But new to the series (as far as I'm aware), they go and shift into this odd type of filming that looks similar to a play being played out on a television as the story is being told during the relevant sequences, and I can't quite seem to figure out what it represents.

**What exactly does this new style represent?**

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to go back and watch it again to see what specific scenes you're referring to, but in I Am Anne Frank (both parts) the style shifts a few times. WWII-era flashback scenes are stylized to look like documentary footage, and I remember the flashback scenes when her husband recounts how her delusion developed also shifted style to something more akin to how scenes shot at that time would look. I take it to symbolize that these scenes are being told from the narrating character's viewpoint, so the visuals gain that period-documentary look.

There's a scene in Part 2 that is styled to resemble a late-60's sitcom. This, I believe, is also done to reflect the viewpoint of her husband, evoking the "perfect family" archetype that pervaded tv shows then.